# Zeros of analytic function and limit points at boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $S$ be the  open ball of center $0$ and radius $1$ with $0$ removed in the complex plane. Is the function $f(z)=\sin(1/z)$ a valid example of analytic function defined in an open subspace whose limit points of zeros cluster at the boundary?

**EDIT**

For open *subspace* I simply mean open *set*.

Existence of limit points for zeros of $f$ is meant in a larger sense, not restrictive as asking for infinte limit points on the boundary, (however, I am really interested in the latter case too).

Comment: what are the zeros of your function?where they are in complex plane?

Comment: You need to add some more details, but the idea is sound. Nitpicking: you mean *domain* or *open set*, not *open subspace*. Also, the exact answer depends on what you mean by *cluster*: do you want the zeros to have *one* accumulation point at the boundary, or do you want the accumulation points to be the entire boundary? (If it's the second case, you need to take another function.)