# Are there exists an analytic function satisfying the following condition

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Let, $D=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|<1\}$. Then there exists a non-constant analytic function$f$ on $D$ such that for all $n=2,3,4,...$

(a) $f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)=0$.

(b) $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$.

(c) $f\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$.

(d) $f\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$.

Which is(/are) correct(/s).

I tried with Identity theorem, but I have some confusion.

From Identity theorem, $S=$ set of all zeros of $f$ has a limit point in $D$ for the options (a) , (b) & (d). So these functions are identically zero. As the function is non-constant so these are NOT possible. So option (c) is only correct.

Am I right? OR wrong?

Comment: Looks good to me, though to complete the answer you have to find a nonconstant function with (c).

Comment: If the zeros have a limit point (in the region of analyticity), then the function is zero. If the function is zero, then the zeros have a limit point in the region of analyticity. But maybe that's not what you meant.

Comment: You might have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301843/zeros-of-analytic-function-and-limit-points-at-boundary

Comment: So, have you had a look? Any thoughts/questions?

Comment: Yes..I saw it..I think you say that $f(z)=\sin (1/z)$ is an example to show that option (c) is correct..But,here how we can show that $f(1-1/n)$ ?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of that example. That function has zeros at $1/\pi,1/(2\pi),1/(3\pi),\dots$. You want a function with zeros at $1/2,2/3,3/4,\dots$. So how can you use the function in the example to build the function you want?

Comment: $f(z)$ should be a function of $z$ only --- it shouldn't have $n$ in it.

Comment: So what will be the function?

Comment: Sorry, but I think someone who is studying complex analysis ought to be able to do the school algebra necessary to turn a function with zeros at $1/\pi,1/2\pi,\dots$ into a function with zeros at $1/2,2/3,\dots$.

Comment: Ok.I got it...It will be $f(z)=\sin\left[\frac{\pi}{1-z}\right]$. I think I am right now...

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint for c. You want $f$ to not be analytic at $z=1$ therefore you may want to try  and play with $z-1$ in a denominator. Now for the points $z=1-\frac{1}{n}$ we have $z-1=-\frac{1}{n}$ so the denominator conveniently disappears and lastly you want $f(1-\frac{1}{n})=0$ for all integers so try to think about periodic functions.